# ¿Como conectar Laravel a una base de datos MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, artisan

Acabo de crear con cmd una base de datos para un proyecto en laravel, use el siguiente código para eso:

```
sudo mysql;

CREATE DATABASE ruleta;

CREATE TABLE USERS (user_id ....);
```

Y como se ve en el siguiente screenshot, dicha tabla existe:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez hecho esto, procedí a editar el archivo .env de laravel y databases.php, los dos acabando así respectivamente:

.env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=ruleta
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

databases.php:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora intente usar php artisan migrate (tengo entendido que eso sirve para crear codigo para migrar datos) y no sirvió

¿Hay algo que estoy haciendo mal? ¿Que es lo que debería hacer?

Quiero que cuando un usuario se registre al sitio sus datos queden en la base de datos

EDIT: Agrego foto del error de php artisan migrate (sé que es codigo, pero no puedo hacer copia/pega desde la maquina virtual hacia windows)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y al ejecutar el comando de `migrate` obtuviste algún error?

Comment: Sí, un error de código en

throw new QueryException

Dice que no se pudo encontrar el driver

Comment: Edita tu pregunta por favor y agrega el mensaje completo a tu pregunta

Comment: De acuerdo, lo hare ahora

Comment: En tu php.ini está habilitada la extensión (extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
)? Tienes instalado el driver pdo-mysql?

 Luego, en tu .env no veo ninguna variable $DATABASE_UL, es posible que sobre la línea 'url'=>env($DATABASE_URL)?

Comment: Busqué en el php.ini, y me dice que no existe ( sale "no se encontraron resultados")

Answer (score 2):

Antes de ejecutar

```
php artisan migrate
```

tienes que ejecutar

```
php artisan migrate:install
```

Ese comando genera una tabla de base de datos que se utiliza para mantener el registro de las migraciones ejecutadas. Esa es la razón de que te truene.

De hecho puedes consultar ese registro con

```
php artisan migrate:status
```

Comment: Lo probé y me da el mismo error que "php artisan migrate"

Comment: Por lo que se ve en la imagen que pusiste donde marca el error, parece que te falta el driver de `PDO de mysql` en la carpeta `ext` de `php` y también habilitar la dll en el `php.ini`. Por otra parte, es posible que tengas versiones incompatibles: una dll de 32 bits y un server de 64 bits o al reves. También importa que la versión de la `dll` sea compatible con la versión de `php`.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que no tienes instalado el driver de PDO_mysql, revisa con `phpinfo()` la version de PHP y la ubicacion de php.ini.

- Instala el driver con `sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql` (Cambia 7.0 por tu version)
- Revisa que en php.ini la linea de `extension=pdo_mysql.so` este sin comentar
- Reinicia tu servidor web (Apache o nginx)

Comment: extension=PDO_mysql? 

O es otra cosa? (también, en php.ini está todo comentado)